# Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Cannot use object of type __PHP_Incomplete_Class as array

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Cannot use object of type __PHP_Incomplete_Class as array | Error thrown in file typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Controller/Page/TreeController.php in line 189
```

This happened after a core update to TYPO3 - 9.5.17

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: This was PHP7.4 - Answer below fixed it.

Comment: I have a similar error. Can you give a little more context where this is happening?

Comment: When trying to open the page tree in typo3 backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91407

The following thanks to Michael Hitzler.

---

As far as I can see there is already a solution within the install tool in class BackendUserConfigurationUpdate.
This seems to address exactly the issue.

Not quite sure in which version the additional migration task has been added, but it helps you solving the issue system wide.

Just got to module Admin Tools -> Update and select Update Wizard.
There you should see a new, not yet executed migragtion task:
Update backend user configuration array
The backend user "uc" array, which is persisted in the db, now only allows for arrays inside its structure instead of stdClass objects. Update the uc structure for all backend users.

Execute this migration task and your BE users will be updated and have a sane uc configuration in the end.

Problem solved and page tree can be loaeded again.

---

```
./typo3cms upgrade:wizard backendUsersConfiguration
```

Should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Module "Maintenance" in "Admin Tools". There you find the card "**Reset Backend User Preferences**".

This solves also the problem.

**Be careful: All be_users settings are getting resetted to default!**